# How to fix 'Expected one of #' in logstash cipher filter plugin?

Tags: logstash

I'm new to logstash. I have a conf file for cipher filter plugin. I have started all the services needed. When I try to run the .conf file it ended with the following Exception. What's wrong with the program? What was the mistake I did in the snippet?

I have looked the past answers,they suggested to replace the double quotes with single quote. But unfortunately it doesn't work for my problem.

Version details:

**OS:** ubuntu 18.04,

**Logstash:** 6.6.2

```
filter {
  cipher {
    algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
    cipher_padding = 1
    iv = '1234567890123456' 
    key = '12345678901234567890123456789012'
    key_size = 32 
    mode = 'encrypt'
    source = 'country'
    target = 'message_crypted'
    max_cipher_reuse = 1
    }
 }
```

**Exception:**

```
message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 16, column 15 (byte 504) after filter {\n  cipher {\n    algorithm ",
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of "=" operator use "=>" operator in logstash for assignment.

See the below code.

filter {
  cipher {
    algorithm => 'aes-256-cbc'
    cipher_padding => 1
    iv_random_length => '1234567890123456' 
    key => '12345678901234567890123456789012'
    key_size => 32 
    mode => 'encrypt'
    source => 'country'
    target => 'message_crypted'
    max_cipher_reuse => 1
    }
 }
```